# Tangent line Exercise. $f (x) = 5e^{−(x−2)^2}$ . Find the coordinates of points where the hill is the most steep.

Tags: optimization, exponential-function

I have this exercise, look easy but I don't know where to start, I think that I need a extra function or value to continue with the calculus.

> Imagine that you are riding over a hill having its profile given by
>   the function $f(x) = 5e^{−(x−2)^2}$ Find the coordinates of points where
>   the hill is the most steep.

Can you help me?. The answer is $x = 2 \pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$

Comment: Do you know how to compute $f'(x)$?

Comment: @addy2012 That's where the hill is the *highest*.  Not the *steepest*.  (In fact the hill will be perfectly level there.)  The hill is steepest when the *derivative* is maximal.  So find f''(x) = 0 and f'''(x) < 0.

Comment: Make a sketch. You want the places where the *absolute value* of the slope is biggest. Let's not worry about absolute value for a while. You can compute the slope at $x$. It is I think $-10(x-2)e^{-(x-2)^2}$. You want this slope to be big in absolute value.

Comment: the $x$-coordinates of the steepest points on the graph of $y = e^{-x^2}$ are $\pm 1/\sqrt 2.$ now you can translate these points by $2$ units to get the answer.

Comment: Actually one caveat.  A hill is steepest when it's increasing (uphill) and increasing at a  maximum *OR* when it's decreasing (downhill) and increasing at  a minimum.  So the hill is steepest when f'(x) is a positive maximum or f'(x) is a negative minimum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice, the slope of the tangent to the curve: $f(x)=5e^{-(x-2)^2}$ is given as 
$$f'(x)=\frac{d}{dx}(f(x))=\frac{d}{dx}(5e^{-(x-2)^2})$$ 
$$=5e^{-(x-2)^2}(-2(x-2))$$$$=-10(x-2)e^{-(x-2)^2}$$
$$f''(x)=-10(x-2)\frac{d}{dx}(e^{-(x-2)^2})-10e^{-(x-2)^2}\frac{d}{dx}(x-2)$$
$$=20(x-2)^2e^{-(x-2)^2}-10e^{-(x-2)^2}$$
$$f'''(x)=-40(x-2)^3e^{-(x-2)^2}+60(x-2)e^{-(x-2)^2}$$
Now, the hill will be most steep at the points where the slope $f'(x)$ is maximum i.e. $f''(x)=0$ hence, $$20(x-2)^2e^{-(x-2)^2}-10e^{-(x-2)^2}=0$$
$$10e^{-(x-2)^2}(2(x-2)^2-1)=0$$
but $e^{-(x-2)^2}\ne 0$, hence
$$2(x-2)^2-1=0$$
$$(x-2)^2=\frac 12$$
$$x-2=\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$$
$$x=2\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$$
Now, substituting these values of $x$ in $f'''(x)$, one should get 
$$f'''\left(2+\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\right)>0, \ \ f'''\left(2-\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\right)<0$$

hence, the slope $f'(x)$ is maximum at the point where $x=2-\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$,hence corresponding y-coordinate of the point $$f\left(2-\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\right)=5e^{-\left(2-2+\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\right)^2}=\frac{5}{\sqrt e}$$
hence, the coordinates of the point where the hill is most steep i.e. slope is maximum is $\color{red}{\left(2-\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}, \frac{5}{\sqrt e}\right)}$

Comment: As @fleablood points out above, you need $f^{(3)} < 0$ as well to ensure these are maxima of the first derivative.

Comment: @HarishChandraRajpoot why did you replace in $f'''$  to  find  $y$  and no in  $f''$ ?

Comment: Actually it's a little more than that  If f'(x) > 0 and f''(x)= 0 and f'''(x) < 0 then then f(x) is increasing and is increasing at its greatest rate.  It's steepest.  Fine.  But if f'(x) < 0 f"(x) = 0 and f'''(x) < 0.  Then f(x) is decreasing but it's at a local maximum which means it is *de*creasing at its *least* rate. So it is *not* at its steepest.  It's at a (locally) *least* steep point.  We need to find f''(x) = 0 and f'(x)>0 while f'''(x)<0 or f'(x)<0 while f'''(x)>0.

Comment: @HarishChandraRajpoot thanks for you answer!

Answer (score 1):

The most steep points are the points were the line tangent is maximum. In other words, you need to find points where $f'(x)$ is maximum.

Comment: Of f'(x) is negative and at a minimum (steepest going downhill).

Comment: Oh, yes, sorry, forgot about minimum.